# GRAILS GSP - Not reloading after one update

Tags: grails, select, gsp

We have a Grails application for User Management which is developed using GSPs. The user details like first name, email, phone are first loaded in a table; We can select a row and click'update' button. The user details are loaded in new popup(GSP) where user edits the details and submit. The updated details are saved in database and the userpage reoloaded with the updated data. But when we click again the 'update' button on the same user, the edit popup which loads does not have the updated details. It still has the details that is fetched last time. When checked, it is found that for the second call, the controller is not getting called. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Strange, did not encounter this one yet. Some caching issues? What happens if you clear the cache and reload the page? (Like Cmd-F5 or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Couple things...

1.) If your using version of the Spring Security plugin set the `cacheUsers` to false.  The security layer is trying to cache it's own user objects and doesn't know you've changed them.  I've ran into this issue before.

2.) If the above isn't the case you'll have to show us your controller call and gsp to better resolve the issue.

-enjoy

Comment: `cacheUsers` should be false because of risk of stale data, and caching doesn't even help much. But it's different data; the "user" cached by Spring Security is the `UserDetails` which is usually just the username, password, and role names. Not person-related data like name, email, etc. unless you've added that to the `UserDetails` with a custom `UserDetailsService`. Changing `cacheUsers` will have no effect on data loaded from the database when you load domain classes, only the data you access from the `Authentication` because you know it's cached and are trusting that it's current.